# Substring depending on Delimiter in the string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ssis

I am writing a procedure in order to handle a file name in SSIS.

Overview:

I am capturing the file name during a Text file load process in SSIS. I have written a procedure in order to split this file name into different components and return the values in form of Variables which I would be using further down the SSIS package.

```
Problem 
This file name is of the format @FileName ="FILE_DATE_REF_DATETIME".All I need 
to split this in a way like "FILE" , "DATE". I am able to achieve this by using
SUBSTRING(@Filename,0,CHARINDEX('_',@FileName))
and
```

`Substring(@FileName,CHARINDEX('_',@FileName)+1,CHARINDEX('_',SUBSTRING(@Filename,CHARINDEX('_',@Filename)+1,Len(@Filename)))-1)`

But here the major problem is when we get an additional '_' in FILE it completely goes wrong. Can anyone please suggest a way that I split the above file name format into FILE and DATE.

**EDIT**

Samples of FileNames:

- asdfkg_20140710_ets20140710_0525_theds
- asdjjf_they_20140710_ets20140710_0525_theds
- oiuth_theyb_wgb_20140710_ets20140710_0526_theds

I need to extract anything before the 20140710 and also 20140710.

Comment: Edit your question and show examples of the file names and the pieces you want to extract.

Comment: How about using a Script Task and Regex for extracting the required details? Is that an option?

Comment: looks like the filename format does not match what the examples show, such as the last part of `DATETIME` in the format is just `theds` (how could this be a datetime?), the `REF` part should not have any underscore but looks like it may have some as the examples show (`ets20140710_0525`, ...), I suppose the `DATE` part here is `20140710`. So the problem becomes more complicated than what you were trying to explain because of the `REF` (it's still unclear if it may contain 1 or even more underscores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) instead of [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

```
select SUBSTRING(@Filename,0,PATINDEX('%[_][0-9]%',@FileName))
```

Comment: the `_` here is a wildcard, not the literal character `_`, that means both asdfkg_20140710_ets20140710_0525_theds and asdfkgs20140710_ets20140710_0525_theds have the same result (note about the ***s*** in the latter filename replacing for the `_`)

Comment: also I've just tried it, looks like `[0..9]` does not work as what it should work in Regex, the pattern here is just 4 characters `0`,`.`,`.`, and `9` (one of them will be chosen to match against the current char).

Answer (score 0):

If the last part of the filename is more reliable (no unexpected underscores), you could `REVERSE` it and use `CHARINDEX` to find the fourth underscore (and reverse the substrings again afterwards).

Otherwise, if you can trust the date format, you can use `PATINDEX` with a horrible expression like

```
'%[_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_]%'
```

Comment: the approach of using `REVERSE` is a good workaround but looks like it's still unclear if it's usable in this case (as I commented under the OP's question), the `REF` part should not contain any underscore or at least we should know if it always contains a **fixed** number of underscore. The example filenames show that it may contain an underscore. Looks like using *PATINDEX* here is better.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest but it will work. LOL

```
DECLARE @FILE VARCHAR(55) = 'FILE_DATE_REF_DATETIME'
DECLARE @FILEFUN AS VARCHAR(55) = LEFT(@FILE,CHARINDEX('_',@FILE))
DECLARE @FILENAMEOUTPUT AS TABLE(Name Varchar(55))

WHILE LEN(@FILE) > 0
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @FILENAMEOUTPUT
SELECT REPLACE(@FILEFUN,'_','')
SET @FILE = REPLACE(@FILE,@FILEFUN,'')
SET @FILEFUN = iif(CHARINDEX('_',@FILE)=0,@FILE,LEFT(@FILE,CHARINDEX('_',@FILE)))
END

SELECT * FROM @FILENAMEOUTPUT
```